# Deploy react-app-rewired and react-app-rewire-less on Heroku

Tags: css, reactjs, heroku, npm, less

I used **react-app-rewired** and **react-app-rewire-less** to apply Less to my app based on React. It works fine locally, but when I deployed it to Heroku, it failed and I got an **Application Error** and a list of errors in Heroku logs.

I have taken two actions:
1) I uninstalled npm and reinstalled it globally to avoid potential bugs.
2) To ensure the two dependencies (react-app-rewired and react-app-rewire-less) work normally, I uninstalled them and installed them again locally by using `npm install [dependency name] --save`, but the application error persists.

Can someone please tell me the root of problems and suggest a solution? Below is my `package.json`.

```
`{
  "name": "portfolio",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "engines": {
    "node": "8.11.1"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "react": "^16.4.2",
    "react-app-rewire-less": "^2.1.2",
    "react-app-rewired": "^1.5.2",
    "react-dom": "^16.4.2",
    "react-scripts": "1.1.4"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-app-rewired start",
    "build": "react-app-rewired build",
    "test": "react-app-rewired test --env=jsdom",
    "eject": "react-app-rewired eject"
  },
  "devDependencies": {}
}`
```

Here are my Heroku error messages:

```
`2018-08-14T09:39:19.000000+00:00 app[api]: Build succeeded
2018-08-14T09:39:22.097727+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `npm start`
2018-08-14T09:39:24.612289+00:00 app[web.1]:
2018-08-14T09:39:24.612308+00:00 app[web.1]: > portfolio@1.0.0 start /app
2018-08-14T09:39:24.612310+00:00 app[web.1]: > react-app-rewired start
2018-08-14T09:39:24.612312+00:00 app[web.1]:
2018-08-14T09:39:26.199701+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/node_modules/react-app-rewire-less/index.js:28
2018-08-14T09:39:26.199764+00:00 app[web.1]: ...cssRules.loader,
2018-08-14T09:39:26.199766+00:00 app[web.1]: ^
2018-08-14T09:39:26.199768+00:00 app[web.1]:
2018-08-14T09:39:26.199770+00:00 app[web.1]: TypeError: cssRules.loader is not iterable
2018-08-14T09:39:26.199772+00:00 app[web.1]: at /app/node_modules/react-app-rewire-less/index.js:28:23
2018-08-14T09:39:26.199774+00:00 app[web.1]: at Object.override [as webpack] (/app/config-overrides.js:5:12)
2018-08-14T09:39:26.199776+00:00 app[web.1]: at Object.<anonymous> (/app/node_modules/react-app-rewired/scripts/start.js:13:13)
2018-08-14T09:39:26.199778+00:00 app[web.1]: at Module._compile (module.js:652:30)
2018-08-14T09:39:26.199780+00:00 app[web.1]: at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:663:10)
2018-08-14T09:39:26.199781+00:00 app[web.1]: at Module.load (module.js:565:32)
2018-08-14T09:39:26.199783+00:00 app[web.1]: at tryModuleLoad (module.js:505:12)
2018-08-14T09:39:26.199784+00:00 app[web.1]: at Function.Module._load (module.js:497:3)
2018-08-14T09:39:26.199786+00:00 app[web.1]: at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:693:10)
2018-08-14T09:39:26.199787+00:00 app[web.1]: at startup (bootstrap_node.js:188:16)
2018-08-14T09:39:26.199789+00:00 app[web.1]: at bootstrap_node.js:609:3
2018-08-14T09:39:26.224092+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
2018-08-14T09:39:26.224599+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! errno 1
2018-08-14T09:39:26.226462+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! portfolio@1.0.0 start: `react-app-rewired start`
2018-08-14T09:39:26.226736+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! Exit status 1
2018-08-14T09:39:26.227064+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR!
2018-08-14T09:39:26.227388+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! Failed at the portfolio@1.0.0 start script.
2018-08-14T09:39:26.227672+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.`
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the same issue referenced here: [breaks with NODE_ENV=production](https://github.com/timarney/react-app-rewired/issues/268).

A [workaround](https://github.com/timarney/react-app-rewired/compare/master...joshuagish:master) is linked to in the comments for that issue that adds `const lessLoader = cssRules.loader || cssRules.use` and swaps `cssRules.loader` with `lessLoader` in `react-app-rewire-less/index.js`.

Comment: Thanks for reply!

The workaround in that link suggests change a few lines inside `react-app-rewire-less/index.js`, but that file is in the 'node_modules' folder which cannot be pushed to the cloud and will be updated by npm. How can I apply this solution to my app?

Comment: I would try forking the repo, applying my changes and then updating your package.json to point to your fork using [GitHub URLs](https://docs.npmjs.com/files/package.json#github-urls)

Answer (score 0):

Just you need to add below dependencies in `dependencies` of `package.json` file.

```
"babel-plugin-import": "^1.12.2",
"less-loader": "^5.0.0",
"react-app-rewire-less": "^2.1.3",
"react-app-rewired": "^2.1.5"
```

And deploy your react app on heroku. It worked for me. I did NOT required to add `NODE_ENV=production` in front of `react-app-rewired start`. Its working fine.